# Obtener la contraseña en texto plano en Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal7

Tengo un sitio en drupal y necesito que cuando los usuarios se loguean obtener la contraseña en texto plano. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera pero no funciona:

```
/**
* Implements hook_user_login()
*/
function mimodulo_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
$contraseña = $edit["pass"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

la forma correcta de obtener la contraseña es:

```
/**
* Implements hook_user_login()
*/
function prueba_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
dpm("Tu contraseña es:");
dpm($edit['values']['pass']);

}
```